# Cannot install Maverick Meerkat

Tags: 10.10, installation, troubleshooting

I have a low-end PC am tired of Windows so I tried to install Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat on my system. I really don't know what's wrong.

After I booted my system with the LiveCD that I got from shipit, my system froze and after almost 5 minues, its default wallpaper comes an error comes right on the face!

> An unexpected error has occured. Ubuntu will now boot in live mode so that you can re-install again. (I dont remember the word-to-word sentence)

And when I try again, it repeats the same old thing. My CD and DVD burner is fine (I checked on a friend's PC who wanted to try Ubuntu.)

These are my specs:

- 2.4ghz P4,
- 256mb DDR1,
- MSI 82865 Intel Chipset,
- 250gb SATA (Free space: 18+8+10+8+22)

P.S: I even tried to install it from a flash but its the same prob again n again.

Comment: Have you tried running memtest86+ to see if your RAM is good?

Comment: Have you verified the checksum for the CD? Have you tried booting off a different distro?

Comment: Suggest changing the subject to a less generic one ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements you will see that recommended minimum system requirements of Ubuntu are 512 MiB of system memory (RAM)

There are two install disks, the Desktop (LiveCD) and the Alternate (straight install). The Desktop disk needs a lot of RAM (300Mb+?)to install. The Alternate only needs 64Mb to install.

With 256Mb you should use either Xubuntu(Xfce) or LXDE.

Yes, there are people who will say 256Mb is enough to run Ubuntu, but it will go s-l-o-w-e-r

Comment: Thanks a lott!! But seriously, im disappointed.. i really wanted to use ubuntu.. /i dont know about xubuntu but i had used the former and have always recommended my clients to go for it.Anyways.. I got my answer.. That is: No ubuntu till the next upgrade. :| The mods can close this question now... Thanks once again! :)